# Android Quick Return Pattern Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-toolbar

I want to use the quick return pattern which is described here:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html

When i use a webview this webview must have the fullscreen height of the device to implement it correctly. Then i have to inject a paddingTop to the body tag on the html in the webview to get the correct margin/padding from top. But there is a problem if the toolbar isnt shown and the site loads new content with javascript which cant scroll. First there is a ugly white area on the top off the webview and second the toolbar cant get shown because the site cant scroll.

Is there any best practice for this behaviour?

Is the javascript injection the correct way?

Comment: How did you solve this? Having the same problem.

Comment: Yes i have found a solution but there is a better solution from Google: The new Android Design Library http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Alright will look into that link, thanks. However, how did you solve it? Did you change the height of the webview? Another solution I'm thinking of is to have the webview 100% and overflowing bottom when not user are a top, and change to normal position when user have scrolled toolbar height.

Comment: In my CustomWebviewClient class i show the ActionBar/Toolbar in the onPageStarted method.

Comment: Hum, how does that work? since it only notifies you when the page started loading right?

Comment: @Zenco - the collapsible/scrollable toolbar wont work with webview. because we cant put a webview inside the nestedScrollView. the child inside NSV will grow to its fullest and it wont be desirable in webview